# Nuxt: Hydration of static page fails (asyncData missing)

Tags: javascript, static, nuxt.js, payload, generate

Once again I have a nuxt question:

I have some static pages which make use of [`asyncData`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/#async-data).
In my asyncData I load data from a JSON file. On the server I do that via filesystem and on the client with axios.

This looks more or less like this:

```
async asyncData({ app, route, store, error, $axios }) {
  try {
    let json
    const slug = 'mypage'

    if (process.server) {
      json = JSON.parse(
        require('fs').readFileSync(
          `static/pages/pages.de.${slug}.json`,
          'utf8'
        )
      )
    } else {
      json = await $axios.$get(`/pages/pages.de.${slug}.json`).then((res) => {
        return res
      })
    }

    return {
      page: json.items[0],
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('e: ', e)
    error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found', e })
  }
}
```

This works like expected and I get my page data like expected.
One weird thing is happening though.
When I run `nuxt generate` to serve my pages in full static mode my pages are pregenerated. Therefore the `server` request is made and `page` is filled with the JSON data. The data is then rendered into a static HTML. All good...

But when I load up that static HTML (initial entry point, not after route change!) the hydration is not being done!

In my network tab I can see a `payload.js` and a `state.js` (vuex stuff) being loaded. But  `this.page` remains undefined forever...

In my understanding `this.page` should be filled with data from the `payload.js` right after loading it.

Because my template includes a `v-if`

```
<template>
  <div v-if="page" class="Page">
    // page content
  </div>
</template>
```

Everything inside that `v-if` breaks.
Click handlers etc.

This problem exists only on the initial entry points. If I go to another route and come back it works perfectly fine...

I use the newest stable nuxt `v2.15.8`.
Also I have pages with a very similar setup where things work like expected.
So if anyone has a clue where I could look for errors or give me a hint if I misunderstand some concepts, I would be very glad to hear.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I finally found the solution.
Just to state things clearly:

- the page should be hydrated with the payload.js
- things should work just normally!

In my case I had a function in my `nuxt.config` that told the app which routes to generate. Some routes seemed to have **missed** a **leading slash**, which broke the whole thing...

Although the route generation process worked just fine, I believe that the payload.js was then not "fitting" the current route...

I don't have the details, but missing leading slashes in my routes was the problem.
So if anyone experiences the same, you could just make sure your routes are correct...

‍♀️

Comment: That's a really good catch. Took me your article to find out what's wrong. I opened a ticket with Vue on Github https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/10469